# Is it possible to create a new type of event for the eventlistener in javascript?

Tags: javascript, events, event-handling, addeventlistener

Long story short: I'm recently working with the leap motion and I need to synchronize with a finished program and the easiest way would be to change the event listener and then simply add the leap function. Any ideas about how to create a new type?

Comment: what kind of new event do you want?

Comment: New event with the Leap. Something like addEventListener("if you can see my right hand",function) ;
(There is a function in the Leap, that returns the hand type like "right" or "left".)

Comment: I think you can do it.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CustomEvent/CustomEvent